# JavaFX - Setting focusedProperty Listener on a custom node

Tags: java, javafx, listener, custom-controls

I have a custom TimePicker node that I have made and it is mostly working, but I need to be able to add a listener to check when it Gaines or looses focus. The issue is that it is not detecting when I am focused on it.

```
public class TimePicker extends HBox {
    private NumberField nbxH; // NumberField is a custom class that extends Textbox. `focusedProperty().addListener` works as expected for this node.
    private Label lblColon;
    private NumberField nbxM;
    private Button btnAmPm;

    public TimePicker() {
        // for testing
        this.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            printDebug("--TIME PICKER FOCUSED PROPERTY-------------------------"
                    + "\n" + observable 
                    + "\n" + oldValue 
                    + "\n" + newValue 
                    );
        });

        nbxH = new NumberField();
        /* nbxH setup */

        lblColon = new Label(":");

        nbxM = new NumberField();
        /* nbxM setup */

        btnAmPm = new Button("AM");
        /* btnAmPm setup */
    }

    /* other methods */
}
```

When in the class itself, I can check if each of the children are focused. I want to add a listener to check if any of the children are focused or if none of the children are focused. In other words, if any of the children are focused, then `isFocused` is `true` and if none of them are focused then `isFocused` is `false`; and I can set a listener to check for that to change. The problem is, `isFocused` is set as final and can't be overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For each of the children elements add a listener that checks if any of the elements are focused and set the focus of the parent to the result. Once I realized `setFocused` was an option, this became quite obvious.

```
nbxM.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    this.setFocused(nbxH.isFocused() | nbxM.isFocused() | btnAmPm.isFocused());
});
```

Comment: instead of listening to each of the children, you could listen to the scene's focusOwner property and check whether it's a child of your pane

Comment: Could you give some code to show me what that might look like?